# Pass a directory of pdf files for performing OCR and generate .txt files for each converted file in Python

Tags: python, loops, pdf, file-handling, python-tesseract

I have a directory containing pdf files. I have written the code that performs OCR when you pass a filename to an object of the wand.image class. What I want to do presently is to loop over the directory of pdf files and generate a OCR'd txt file for each pdf and save it some directory. The code that I have written till now is as follows:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi




pdf = wi(filename = r"D:\files\aba7d525-04b8-4474-a40d-e94f9656ed42.pdf", resolution = 300)

pdfImg = pdf.convert('jpeg')

imgBlobs = []

for img in pdfImg.sequence:
    page = wi(image = img)
    imgBlobs.append(page.make_blob('jpeg'))

extracted_text = []

for imgBlob in imgBlobs:
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
    extracted_text.append(text)

print(extracted_text[0])
```

Any suggestions on how I can generate the .txt files from the OCR'd pdf's

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the end of your code:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as result:
     for line in extracted_text:
          result.write(line,'\n')
```

Comment: The thing is if you see my code, ("pdf = .."), I have hardcoded a filename in my code but I need to pass a directory there so that all the files in that directory can be OCR'd and also I need to take as output all those files with their filenames with just .pdf being replaced by .txt. How can I do that